# giving two background colors for html with css not working

Tags: html, css, forms, input, background

i have a form to be displayed in HTML format, the form HTML code is like below:

```html
<form action="<?php echo base_url('editAllProductsAction'); ?>" method="post">
  <?php foreach($products as $key=>$val){ ?>
  <div class="row">
    <h5></h5>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $val['id']; ?>" name="id[]" />
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <label>Product Name</label>
      <input name="product_name[]" value="<?php echo $val['product_name']; ?>" type="text" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <label>Min Qty </label>
      <select name="min_qty[]" class="form-control">
        <?php for($i=1;$i<50;$i++){ ?>
        <option <?php if($i==$val[ 'min_qty']) echo 'selected'; ?> value="
          <?php echo $i; ?>">
          <?php echo $i; ?>
        </option>
        <?php }?>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <label>Purchase Price </label>
      <input name="purchase_price[]" value="<?php echo $val['purchase_price']; ?>" type="number" data-id="<?php echo $val['id']; ?>" class="form-control edit_purchase_price" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <label>Nosh Price </label>
      <input name="nosh_price[]" value="<?php echo $val['nosh_price']; ?>" type="number" class="form-control edit_nosh_price_<?php echo $val['id']; ?>" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary right_side">Submit</button>
</form>
```

as you can see I have used php to display the values in the form, when I am displaying the form, because all the row is having same white color as background like below, which is awkward:

[image]

I am trying to give 2 background colors for the form, like in first row all input background color will display one color, the second row all the input background will show different colors and it continues for each row. i did the following css:

```css
.form-control:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

but this is not displaying the color, can anyone tell me what I did wrong here. thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure what you meant is not the `:nth-of-type`-selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:nth-child(2n+1) part of your code will work for `form-control` class living on the same level as siblings. There is no other `form-control` class as sibling on the same level. They live inside different column. That's why 2n+1 cannot find the third `form-control` inside it's own level. So, basically you have to target the class `col-lg-3` as the :nth-child(2n+1). Like so should work-

```
.col-lg-3:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

That way you are selecting every other column and then the eventual `form-control` class if you want to style them differently per column basis.

You can visually see it here- https://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/

Edit:
With further clarification, here is the code that should work in this case and the above explanations stands with a little bit of selector change-

```
.row:nth-child(2n+1) .form-control {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: this is not what i am looking for bro, something like .row:nth-child(2n+1){
background: grey;
}, but only to the input background, how do I specify the input background in this

Comment: Then you just select the .form-control like so- .row:nth-child(2n+1) .form-control. Once the nth row/column is selected, you just select the input inside it by adding the classname with a space as normal seelctor and set background-color: gray.

Comment: Can you copy the generated html from page source and add it a jsfiddle fiddle and provide the link?

Comment: bro can u open a chat

Comment: bro can u open a chat

Answer (score 1):

You have to give the class row instead of form-control

```
.row:nth-child(2n+1){
background: grey;
}
```

Comment: almost what i am looking for, but I want to specify that only the input background color is changed

Comment: then you can do something like this `.row:nth-child(2n+1) > input { background: grey}`